# How can I move my labels to the right with CSS?

Tags: css, dynamic, margin, padding

I have a button that was dropped on my Webform at design-time, followed by a slew of Label/Checkbox pairs that are added dynamically at browse-time.

I've moved the button off the left edge of the page, and added some speacing between the dynamically-created controls, too, but the labels refuse to budge off the out-of-bounds marker, even though I've tried adding margin and padding values to move them right off the left edge of the page.

Here is my CSS:

```
<style>
    #Button1 {
        margin: 12px;
        padding: 12px;
    }

    label {
        margin: 24px;
        padding-left: 32px;
    }

    input[type='checkbox'] {
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
</style>
```

...and here is how it looks:

[image]

Why does neither margin nor padding-left budge the Labels? How can I get them to wake up and feel the boot in their gutter?

BTW, I create the Labels and Checkboxes like so in the code-behind:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count - 1
    ' for testing, limit count TODO - remove or comment out
    If i > 11 Then 'There are thousands...just grab enough to fit on the page without scrolling for now...
        Exit For
    End If
    Dim coName = New Label()
    ' Must prepend with something, as controls cannot share the same ID
    coName.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString()
    coName.Text = categoryDT.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)

    Dim chk = New CheckBox()
    chk.ID = "ckbx" + i.ToString()
    chk.Checked = True
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)

    ' Add a "line break" after each checkbox
    Dim l = New Label()
    l.Text = "<br>"
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(l)
Next
```

### UPDATE

At Linx's suggestion, I tried this where the Label/Checkbox pairs are created:

```
Dim divBegin = New Label
divBegin.Text="<div padding-left = 20px; >"
formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(divBegin)

For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count - 1
   . . . ' code elided for brevity
Next

Dim divEnd = New Label
divEnd.Text="</div>"
formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(divEnd)
```

...but it does naught.

### UPDATE 2

It would really complicate my logic to do what Linx is suggesting in his second answer. I don't see why it's impossible to take care of this with css. The checkbox css is working; the button css is working; why is the label css not working? Even when I do this, and try to brute force the issue:

```
label {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 24px !important;
    padding-left: 32px !important;
}
```

...it still doesn't work - the labels stubbornly stick to the left side, like  bulldog barnacles biting a British bobby bloke.

### UPDATE 3

Bizarrely enough (too much!), even this (prepending 5 spaces to the label's text) doesn't work:

```
coName.Text = "     "+ categoryDT.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
```

?!?

Ears flared, trunk raised, and trumpet blaring!!!

Comment: I think labels are inline and they dgaf. Try inline-block them mofos.

Comment: How to do that in the dynamically-generated Labels? I see no "padding" or "margin" or such properties available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party but the correct solution is simple

A .NET [`Label`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx) (Not to be mistaken with HTML [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)) is a .NET Web Control.

A `Label` is sent back to the browser as a **`<span>`** therefore the browser doesn't recognize the css `label` selector.

To style `Label` use `span` selector instead:

```
span {
    margin-left: 24px;
    padding-left: 32px;
}
```

In this case the paddings/margins will work

---

BTW

You can add classes to `Label` in the code behind using `CssClass` property:

```
coName.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString()
coName.Text = categoryDT.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
coName.CssClass = "foo-class"
formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
```

And then use the class in the css:

```
.foo-class {
    margin-left: 24px;
    padding-left: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping everything in a div and giving that some padding?

Comment: See the Update; I tried it, but am apparently doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this dynamically, I think your easiest bet would be to do it simply in HTML and CSS like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    (html for labels)
</div

.wrapper {
    padding: 0 32px;
}
```

Comment: Still don't know how to do this, since I'm adding these dynamically; there's more to it than just adding some css.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have HTML which has two div one is parent div and another is child div like below

```
<div class="maindiv">
<div class="childlabeldiv">
     Align label to right
</div>
</div>
```

You can use below css to align label at right with other css that you need

```
.maindiv{
  width: 100%;
}
.childlabeldiv{
   text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This rather simple approach - adding padding to the form - works:

```
#formCustCatMaint {
    padding: 4em;
}
```

It also adds padding to the button, but that's okay, too.

If somebody wants to add an answer based on this, I'll be glad to award the open 50-point bounty to them.